# Store is loaded twice after data.Model.save()

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I have a grid with remote data (php/mysql/json) and use a form to insert records or to edit this data.
I use the api configuration of the proxy/store. I use MVC architecture.

So, all very simple (in pseudo code):

- get selected model form grid or create model
- frm.loadRecord()
- frm.updateRecord()
- frm.getRecord().save()

and all works fine, but I noticed in the browser console that after the POST *(works fine, calls either the url configured with create or the url configured with update)*, the store calls (GET) the url configured with retrieve twice. These calls are identical.

So functionally all works fine and I could ignore it, but now I've noticed I want it fixed.

Can anyone help me where to look? Thanks in advance.

---

Details:

It's all really basic:

In the controller of the gridpanel:

```
updateRow: function (gridpanel) {

        var sm = gridpanel.getSelectionModel();
        var record = sm.getLastSelected();

        this.showForm(record);

}
```

and

```
showForm: function (record) {

    ...

    formpanel.show();

    var frm = formpanel.getForm();
    frm.loadRecord(record);     

}
```

In the controller of the formpanel:

```
submit: function(frm) {

    frm.updateRecord();
    frm.getRecord().save(); 

}
```

When I remove the save action the GET requests aren't called, so this seems to trigger them.

In the store:

```
api: {
            create: '../php/api/customers.php?request=create',
            read: '../php/api/customers.php?request=retrieve&scope=summary',
            update: '../php/api/customers.php?request=update',
            destroy: '../php/api/customers.php?request=delete'
        }
```

The screenshot:

[image: screenhot]

Comment: Could you provide some of your code to replicate the issue or even better, a [fiddle](http://fiddle.sencha.com)

Comment: Also, post please screenshots of both requests from the Developer Tools Network tab.

Comment: Thanks for tour comments, I will post more details as soon as I have the opportunity.

Comment: You could add a load handler to the store and then breakpoint there and work through the stack trace to see what code of yours is triggering it both times

Comment: I've added the details.

Comment: you can check your `autoLoad` in your store, or `afterrender` in your controller. I had same issue like you, because I load it in `afterrender` and `autoLoad:true` in my store, any way there must be another function load that.... :D